# Does ethereum support re-keying?

Tags: addresses, private-key

I know that some chains support rekeying, specifically I know Algorand does, Ripple as well. I could not find a definitive answer anywhere so I thought I'd try my luck here

Comment: Could you please define what is meant by re-keying?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekeying_%28cryptography%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating private key to prevent it to be used too much or for one time use it not an Ethereum protocol feature but can be done in wallets. I don't know of any wallet doing this automatically though. Rotating keys is not needed from a security point of view but only if you want to separate accounts. It will best work with an HD wallet able to generate a infinite number of keys from a single seed.